# Installation/Configuration of Apache GUI web interface

Tags: apache-2.4, maven

I have a stand alone Windows Server 2019 on an AD network. I have been tasked with some configuration of this server that I will develop php web things on in the future. I currently have server admin access to the server, but that will eventually be removed when the setup is complete.

Therefore it has been suggested that I configure a web based admin tool to admin the apache web server we intend to use on it and 'Apache GUI' has been mentioned as a solution for this.

https://github.com/jrossi227/ApacheGUI

I have looked at the documentation on the above page, and I have followed the instructions to install Maven and Java on the server as it says they are required, set up Env vars etc

I have run the suggested command to ensure that Maven is installed correctly and it prints out this version info to confirm this:

```
C:\Windows\system32>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.8.6 (84538c9988a25aec085021c365c560670ad80f63)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.6
Java version: 18.0.2.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.2.1
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "windows server 2019", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

I have downloaded apache gui from the above link, but the instruction steps from here confuse me, as they seem to be missing key info.

It says:

> Windows build steps
> Navigate to the root directory in the source project (Where pom.xml is located).
> Open pom.xml and set the environment property in pom.xml to Windows64. The apachegui.home property uses the environment property to determine the location of ApacheGUI.
> Run the Maven builds below.

If I try to follow any of the next steps, the command prompt will give me the following expected error:

```
C:\Windows\System32>mvn clean package -P prod
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.270 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-08-31T13:02:34+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "prod" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\Windows\System32). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

This must be because I've not done anything with the apachegui files yet. I've extracted them into a folder on the desktop, but these instructions seem to skip telling me where I should put them.

So I then assumed that, it's just command prompt running Maven trying to work in whatever directory I happened to be in at the time, and it just wanted me to be in the apachegui directory in question first, so working on that assumption, I moved the extracted apachegui folder so that the subfolder with the POM file it's talking about is now in:

C:\Program Files\ApacheGUI\tomcat\webapps\ApacheGUI\META-INF\maven\net.apachegui\ApacheGUI

the Pom file already seems to have the correct windows64 variable set, so there was nothing to change there.

Then I attempted to run the following command from the installation page:

```
mvn clean install -P prod
```

This prints out many many lines telling me it's download things from maven.apache.org and at the end, it says the following:

```
[INFO] Executing tasks
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  34.176 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-08-31T14:12:34+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (ant-packagejs) on project ApacheGUI: An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[ERROR] java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\ApacheGUI\tomcat\webapps\ApacheGUI\META-INF\maven\net.apachegui\ApacheGUI\build.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

C:\Program Files\ApacheGUI\tomcat\webapps\ApacheGUI\META-INF\maven\net.apachegui\ApacheGUI>
```

At which point I am lost. There is indeed no file called build.xml in the folder in question, it was not there in the apachegui extracted files before I ran this command. I'm totally unfermilair with the Maven thing, and I'm only using it to get this Apachegui working, so I'm unsure if this process was supposed to make this file further up, or if I've missed something else.

I also noticed that the requirements for this apachegui state that node.js is required, but the instructions make no mention of installing it, or where I would put it or what to do with it.

Any guidence would be appriciated.

Note: This is my first post on the serverfault part of stackexchange, so I apoligise if I've given too much info, but I'm trying to state the whole senario so I'm not creating an XY problem.